# "Imagine, for a second, what Marcus’s life as an emperor must have been like". - how to understand "must have been"?

Tags: present-perfect, modal-verbs

Help me understand the logic of using must + perfect in this sentence:

> Imagine, for a second, what Marcus’s life as an emperor must have been like

Comment: “Must have been” is used to express an assumption, or an opinion that you gathered from a logical guess.

Comment: Person A: a car ran over my foot. Person B: That must have hurt!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you! Can't I simply use "must be"? Wouldn't it express the same idea of an assumption based on a logical guess? It also conveys probability.

Comment: The past perfect “have been” implies that Marcus no longer lives life as an emperor. For example, if “Marcus” refers to Marcus Aurelius.

Comment: "must be" is possible in the simple present tense, but you can't really use the present tense for someone who is dead.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks! For the past could I say "...had to be like"? Is it different from "must have been like"?

Comment: Not really.  "must have been" is the most natural way to express this.  "To imagine what life must have been like for someone" is a very common way to talk about what life was like for people in the past, from their point of view.

Comment: If you use the less-favoured ***had to be*** (or ***had to have been***, to stick with Past Perfect)  rather than ***must have been***, then IF your audience / readers assume you're a competent native speaker, they will assume you had some reason for doing so. The obvious reason that comes to mind for me is ***had to** be / have been* emphasizes the idea that *Marcus himself **had no choice** but to live like that*, whereas with ***must*** the lack of an alternative tends rather to apply to the ***addressee*** (who ***must*** think in a certain way, in line with logic and current evidence).